# window.close() not working correctly in IE(11)/Chrome?

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, download

I'm making an AJAX call to a site which generates a query and then saves it to a .txt file.
This file should be downloaded after the AJAX was done and close that download window.
Howether IE closes it automatically and then tries to close the mainwindow, which **shouldn't** be closed.
Meanwhile Chrome only closes the download window which is what IE should do aswell..
Is there a workaround for this?

```
function start(){
   $.ajax({
        url: ('query.php'),
        type: 'POST',
        async:false,
        data: { 
        id: id,
        intnr: intnr
        },
        dataType: "html"
         })
          .done (function(response) { window.open('download.php');  window.close('download.php'); })
          .fail (function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(xhr.responseText); })
        ;
}
```

download.php is just :

```
<?php
header ( 'Content-Type: text/html');
header ( "Content-Disposition: 'attachment'; filename='File.txt'");
include ('/xx/xx/query.txt');
?>
```

**EDIT :** Workaround but it is working now..
shortened function to

```
.done (function(response) { var download_window = window.open('download.php'); })
```

added into download.php

```
<script>
var s = navigator.userAgent; 
if(s.indexOf("Chrome") > -1 == true) 
{ 
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you create an HTML link to download.php and then click it? Does it show query.txt or open a download dialogue box? If it shows the file, modify the headers in download.php to force download of query.txt and instead of using window.open and .close just load with window.location = "download.php" (or some similar function).

Comment: Tried so, it downloads the file. But how can I achieve that after the query.txt is filled it's downloaded? My only thought was to window open download.php..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this then:

```
.done (function(response) {
    var download_window = window.open('download.php');
    download_window.close();
 })
```

.. should make IE not close anything else.

Comment: It flashed by but no download was starting. Worked in Chrome howether as it also was flashing by for a sec.

Comment: Check the other answer with the updated window.location.href line. That works for me.

Comment: @Yado 
Try attaching onload event on download_window object and close the window in it.
`download_window.onload = function() { download_window.close(); }`

Comment: LGT : as said, I tried but it just refreshed my page, no download window or something like that. :(
@Ritesh strange.. it works now in IE..howether doesn't close anymore in Chrome. I dont get it..

Comment: @Yado, see what does it give in alert.
`alert(!download_window.onload);` Put it after window.open call.

Comment: @Ritesh Both sent true, howether only the IE windows closes (but it does without the window.close() aswell, seems like it's inbuilt)

Comment: Got it working now (see edit), maybe not the best way to do it but it's the only that works at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, but offers an alternative.

Try something like this in the jQuery code:

```
.done (function(response) { window.location.href = "download.php"; })
```

.. and add headers to force download in download.php:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
// Removed this from my code.
// header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
// Added this for yours.. not sure exactly what's optimal for your case.
header("Content-Type: text/html");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=File.txt");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("/xx/xx/query.txt");
```

In my project, this php code was run after clicking a submit button (form) and if I recall correctly, it just showed a download dialogue box without updating the address bar or showing an empty page.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, could it be because I have the page with the function included? It just jumps to my first Navtab.

Comment: Which page and what function are you referring to?

Comment: I've got my view which contains a navbar with 4 pages, all included. on the 4th there's a button, on the click it runs the function start(). 

I've followed your tipps but it just jumped, after clicking it, to the first Navtab :/

Comment: Do you have a link to this page? What happens if you type the full address to download.php and load it manually? Do you get a download window?

Comment: It's done via <input type="button"> and an onclick-function. And yes, I get the download window when I type the download.php adress.

Comment: Is download.php in the same directory/folder as the JS file running the code?.. try window.location("http://the.full.address.com/download.php").

Comment: Yup, both in the same directory.

Comment: Try using the full address anyway.. try opening some other address. The problem isn't with PHP, as you have noticed, but with the JS code.

Comment: tried so and all it does is refreshing the whole page as it seems. no download window at all

Answer (score 0):

This will work if it is rad window

```
function GetRadWindow() {
                var oWindow = null;
                if (window.radWindow)
                    oWindow = window.radWindow;
                else if (window.frameElement && window.frameElement.radWindow)
                    oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
                return oWindow;
            }

function selfClose(){
GetRadWindow().close();
}
```